# SilverStripe 3: Loop greatgrandchildren pages WITH OUT grouping by parent

Tags: sorting, loops, templates, silverstripe

In my template I'm looping my child pages as 2 separate lists and then their grandchild pages under these. But I want these greatgrandchild pages to be sorted as an entire list and not divided / grouped by their parents.
Simply loop after loop does not work as all greatgrandchild pages should be put in order and not grouped by parent then sorted.

I know this could be done by a function to get all the greatgrandchildpages and sort them by a chosen method (e.g. alphabetically). But I don't want to get ALL of them as I need them just the grandchildren for each child.

PAGE - to show list

Child - List Heading

GrandChild - not shown in list

GreatGrandChild - Listed and ALL sorted Alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Page you can get the IDs of all children (which are parents of the grand children) using [getIDList()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_getIDList):

```
$ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
```

Now you can get all Pages (or whatever pagetype you want) by ParentID:

```
$grandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $ids));
```

Same for grand-grandchildren....

```
$grandGrandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $grandChildren->getIDList()));
```

You can sort this DataList by whatever you want, e.g.

```
$sortedgrandGrandChildren = $grandGrandChildren->sort('Title', 'ASC');
```

**edit:**

$this->Children() does return an ArrayList, not a DataList, so we have to get all children manually. Be aware, this doesn't respect `canView()`, so we get *all* pages, if the current user has permissions or not. For a simple website this should be ok.

Using `$this->Children()->column('ID')` you get the filtered result.

A ready to use method could be:

```
public function getGrandGrandChildren() {
    $ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
    $grandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $ids));
    $grandGrandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $grandChildren->getIDList()));

    return $grandGrandChildren->sort('Title', 'ASC');
}
```

And in your template:

```
<% loop $GrandGrandChildren %>
    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
    //do whatever you want
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Excuse my naivety but do I need to put these into a function? And then loop $sortedgrandGrandChildren in my template? I added each of your lines in my page.php in separate functions but am getting "undefined variable" Should I be putting them into the page.php like this:
 `public function sortedgrandGrandChildren() {
 $sortedgrandGrandChildren = $grandGrandChildren->sort('Title', 'ASC');
 }`
if you could give me an example that would be amazingly helpful.
Thank you

Comment: This is great thank you. Although I'm actually sorting by ProductReleaseDate but trying to use this instead of Title gives me an error: ORDER BY "ProductReleaseDate" ASC Unknown column 'ProductReleaseDate' in 'field list'. Do I need to add some more code for it to find these?

Comment: if you want to get all ProductPage items you need ProductPage::get() (or whatever your classname is like) if you want to filter on a Field of that class. Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've got a get() for ProductPage `function ProductPages()
    {
    $productPages = ProductPage::get();
    return $productPages ? $productPages : false;
    }` but the issue is trying to then group these by their grandparents, so I get two separate lists and not ALL products sorted by ProductReleaseDate.. any thoughts?

Comment: Ignore last comment. Thank You!!! `$grandGrandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $grandChildren->getIDList()));` did it! Who knew it would be this tricky (for me)

Answer (score 1):

`SiteTree::get()->filter('ParentID',SiteTree::get()->filter('ParentID',$this->Children()->column('ID')))->filterByCallback(function($page){return $page->canView()})`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: `filterByCallback()` is filtering in PHP and therefore a bit unperformant. If you can make it filter in DB it'd be better IMHO